# Recolector basura Java y tipos primitivos

Tags: java

me ha pasado muchas veces de querer declarar variables dentro de bucles para hacer una tarea y me surge la siguiente duda: por ejemplo, me invento un código, este:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        int var = i;
        // Hacer cosas con var
    }
}
```

La pregunta es: el recolector de basura supongo que aquí no interviene porque sólo funciona con objetos. Pero qué pasa cuando en la segunda iteración del bucle for se vuelve a definir la variable `var`, la anterior variable se destruye u ocupa lugar en memoria junto con las 50 veces más que se va a declarar?

Comment: Solo como referencia, mirarias el [tour]? muy buena pregunta, muy clara y bien formulada...

Answer (score 2):

Estos son *detalle de implementación* de los que ni podemos estar 100% seguros, ni debemos asumir que siempre estarán implementados de la misma manera que lo están ahora, pues podrían cambiar entre distintas implementaciones de la JVM o sufrir cambios de diseño en el futuro.

Dicho esto, lo más seguro es que las variables `i` y `var`, al ser variables locales de tipos primitivos, sean declaradas dentro de la [pila de la JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.2). La memoria de estas variables es *liberada* cuando salen de contexto.

La documentación dice:

> Each Java Virtual Machine thread has a private Java Virtual Machine stack, created at the same time as the thread. A Java Virtual Machine stack stores frames (§2.6). A Java Virtual Machine stack is analogous to the stack of a conventional language such as C: **it holds local variables** and partial results, and plays a part in method invocation and return. Because the Java Virtual Machine stack is never manipulated directly except to push and pop frames, frames may be heap allocated. The memory for a Java Virtual Machine stack does not need to be contiguous.

Mi traducción libre de dicho párrafo es:

> Cada hilo de Java Virtual Machine tiene una pila privada de Java Virtual Machine, creada al mismo tiempo que el hilo. Una pila de la máquina virtual de Java almacena marcos (*frames*) (§2.6). Una pila de máquina virtual Java es análoga a la pila de un lenguaje convencional como C: **contiene variables locales** y resultados parciales, y juega un papel en la invocación y devolución de métodos. Debido a que la pila de la máquina virtual Java nunca se manipula directamente excepto para insertar y desplegar marcos, los marcos pueden asignarse en el *heap*. No es necesario que la memoria de una pila de la máquina virtual Java sea contigua.

(el énfasis es mío).

Tomando como base lo dicho en la documentación y la analogía a la pila del lenguaje C:

En el caso de la variable `var`, se crea un nuevo *stack frame* al entrar a cada iteración del ciclo `for`, y se regresa a la posición original en el stack al concluir el mismo, por lo que seguramente va a utilizar la misma dirección en todas las interaciones.

Ocurre lo mismo en el contexto de la variable `i`, cuyo *stack frame* es creado al entrar al ciclo y liberado al concluirlo.

Tanto la *creación* como la *liberación* de dichas variables es manejada de manera automática por java.

Comment: es decir, que para el contexto del codigo del usuario var se crea la cantidad de veces que se ejecute el for, y el recolector las eliminara una vez finalice el ciclo

Comment: El recolector no tiene nada que ver en este asunto. Hablamos de la pila y sus _marcos_ o _frames_. En este lugar van a estar las variables de tipos primitivos y las referencias a objetos que se declaren localmente. Al haber variables declaradas dentro del ciclo for, el frame se va a crear y liberar tantas veces como se ejecute el ciclo (el código para hacerlo es automágicamente creado por el compilador, como ya he dicho, el recolector no tiene nada que ver en este tema).

Comment: bueno no el recolector, el frame

Comment: Entonces por lo que entiendo, lo más seguro es que cuando finalice cada iteración del bucle for se vuelva a crear la variable var destruyendose el anterior declaración no? Veréis el tema es que no sé si declarar las variables fuera de los bucles para luego usarlas dentro para así no ocupar memoria innecesariamente. Creo que a todos nos ha pasado que en lugar de preveer la declaración de todas las variables fuera del for, las vamos creando a medida que surge necesitarlas. Qué opinais?

Comment: El caso del OP no es un detalle de implementación ya que el ámbito (scope) de la variables locales está bien definido en la especificación del lenguaje. La variable es destruída con la finalización de la iteración.

Comment: @Mart, Creo que estás _preocupándote_ por algo que no debiera preocuparte tanto (a menos que tu código se vaya a ejecutar en algún dispositivo que tenga realmente poca memoria). OJO, que no digo que no haya que pensar en producir código óptimo, lo que digo es que si se paran creando 50 variables de tipo `int` (cosa que no ocurre) van a ocupar 200 Bytes.  Si fueran 10,000, serían menos de 40KB. Para ocupar 1 MegaByte, tendrías que declarar 262,144 enteros. Y las máquinas actuales suelen tener varios GigaBytes de memoria.